# Sport league app (React.js and Firebase). Looking for solution for results and live table

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I am going to create app for lower division football league using React.js and Firebase. I am on a planning stage and the toughest thing seems to be to write components responsible for adding fixtures, then based on it add results and automatically update league table with points, goals etc. 
I cannot find any module to solve this problem. Maybe anyone has been done similar app and can advise me. I wonder what will be better, find a cms or write everything from scratch. Thanks for help ;)